# NodeJS - Google API Module - [TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined]

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services, google-api-nodejs-client

I installed the nodejs module "googleapis" (`npm install googleapis`) to an Azure Mobile Services instance and I wanted to do a quick test with some sample code I found here https://www.npmjs.org/package/googleapis. After trying the code sample which creates a text file in google drive I get the following error message in the console:

```
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined]
```

The error is occurring at line 40 of the current version of  google-api-nodejs-client / apis / index.js (https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/index.js):

```
var Endpoint = require(__dirname + '/' + filename + '/' + path.basename(version));
```

When debugging I can see the path used in the above method as the following:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\node_modules\googleapis\apis\drive\v2
```

I have verified that the path is correct.

Here is the code I tried to run:

```
var google = require('googleapis');

var OAuth2Client = google.auth.OAuth2;
var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx';
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxx';
var REDIRECT_URL = 'xxxxx';
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
access_token: identities.google.accessToken
});

var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v2', auth: oauth2Client });

drive.files.insert({
  resource: {
    title: 'Test',
    mimeType: 'text/plain'
  },
  media: {
    mimeType: 'text/plain',
    body: 'Hello World'
  }
}, function(err, response) {
console.log('error:', err, 'inserted:', response.id);
});
```

What is the source of the issue?

Here is the error stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined at Object.<anonymous> 
(D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\node_modules\googleapis\node_modules\multipart-stream\node_modules\sandwich-stream\lib\sandwich-stream.js:24:50) 
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10) 
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32) 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) 
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17) 
    at require (module.js:378:17) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\node_modules\googleapis\node_modules\multipart-stream\index.js:1:78) 
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
```

Here is line 24 of sandwich-stream.js:

```
SandwichStream.prototype = Object.create(Readable.prototype, {
  constructor: SandwichStream
});
```

The nodejs version is:

```
Node version: v0.8.28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Azure Mobile Services is doing something funky with __dirname that is making the file path not resolve correctly. Can you check the logs where you are running this? The actual error should be console.log'd from this line: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/index.js#L45

Comment: The path is the following: D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\node_modules\googleapis\apis/drive/v2 and the error returned on line 45 of index.js is [TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined]

Comment: I confirm that the path is correct. D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\node_modules\googleapis\apis/drive/‌​v2.js is the location of the file on the server.

Comment: I believe the issue is caused by the mixed path separators on Win32 systems. I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/pull/271) just now that will hopefully fix this. If you can, try to modify the *apis/index.js* in your project so that it contains the changes introduced in the PR and let us know if this works for you.

Comment: @RobertRossmann Unfortunately, I had tried this yesterday and it didn't solve my issue. The line which throws the error is `var Endpoint = require('D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\node_modules\googleapis\apis\drive\v2')`. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined]. I also tried adding the .js extension to the path and I have verified that the path is correct using the fs.existsSync() method.

Comment: Interesting. Could you update the question with full stack trace of the error?

Comment: @RobertRossmann I have now added the stack trace of the error to my question. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but version 1.x of google-api-nodejs-client only supports Node 0.10.x. You can see this in the .travis.yml file here: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Thank you Ryan! It makes sense. I will see if I can upgrade to 0.10.x

Comment: Thanks so much for reporting your issues. This has pointed out a few bugs in our code that we are going to address (https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/pull/271 and https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/pull/269). Hopefully upgrading to 0.10.x solves your issues. :)