# How to use latest version of nodejs on azure mobile-service runtime

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to integrate [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) with azure mobile-services. I get following runtime error trying to use sample code from googleapis:

```
Error: Unable to load endpoint plus("v1"): Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

This error seems to be [due to reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579734/nodejs-google-api-module-typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-und) that googleapis only support nodejs version [0.10 and higher](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/.travis.yml), whereas azure mobile-services are running nodejs version 0.8.28.

Is there a way I can use more latest version of nodejs on azure mobile-service?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065987/how-to-use-latest-npm-on-azure-mobile-service-deployment, asked by the same user.

Comment: It looks same question but actually each question addresses different problem on Azure image. One asks for upgrading default 'nodejs', other asks for access to Program Files folder or Environment variable to use different version of 'npm' already installed on Azure image.

Comment: You may be able to follow the workaround from David Ebbo on this forum post, which is about npm. Something similar might work for nodejs: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/068ef026-f80d-4bf8-9f40-5d1af33a1024/git-deployment-fails-with-npm-error-when-resolving-a-package-version-containing-a-?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: thanks lindydonna. But problem with nodejs is that there isn't any newer version of nodejs installed. For npm it works, since there is already newer version installed and you can use it by changing the runtime variable NPM_JS_PATH.
As a sidenote: actually googleapis works fine if you just update the npm path using the work-around. No need for updating nodejs.

Comment: have you figured that out? I tried using package.json as specified here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps/, but it doesn't work for me. I still have an older version of node running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround suggested by David Ebbo on [Azure Support Site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/068ef026-f80d-4bf8-9f40-5d1af33a1024/git-deployment-fails-with-npm-error-when-resolving-a-package-version-containing-a-?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required)

You may want to try something like this as a workaround:

at the root of the repo, you'll find a .deployment file that has:

```
[config]
command = ..\ZumoDeploy.cmd
```

Change it to

```
[config]
command = deploy.cmd
```

And create a deploy.cmd next to it containing:

```
set NPM_JS_PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\npm\1.4.9\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js  
..\ZumoDeploy.cmd
```

Commit both files and push.